# How to pass an object from the application which hosts the WorkflowApplication to a NativeActivity

Tags: c#, android-activity, workflow, workflow-foundation

I do need to talk from a WF activity to the host application. The host application consists of multiple libs. One of those libs starts the WorkflowApplication with an Activity which contains a custom NativeActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use extensions to do just that. Basically you register a custom class that is used to communicate with the host. That class can expose methods that outputs data, for example write data to the Console.

See http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1091/workflow-foundation-40-extension for an introduction.

Comment: You saved my day - perfect

Comment: Glad to be of any help :-)